# How do I find out a program version from a core dump? Can I write it there myself?

Tags: debugging, versioning, coredump

I have a core file, but I am uncertain which version of the program produced it. When I use the `file` command, I get only the binary name, not the version.

```
% file core.20200730-1203
core.20200730-1203: ELF 64-bit LSB core file, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from 'qdrouterd -c /tmp/qdrouterd.json', real uid: 0, effective uid: 0, real gid: 0, effective gid: 0, execfn: '/usr/sbin/qdrouterd', platform: 'x86_64'
```

I can try to give my debugger multiple binaries in turn that I guess are close in version, and see what works and what doesn't.

I believe that the solution is to put a string constant with the version into the program code. Core dumps contain the program code, because it is loaded into memory for execution, and therefore I should be able to recover it using the `strings` command.

Currently, the program contains the following, where `QPID_DISPATCH_VERSION` is a preprocessor macro.

```
qd_log(router->log_source, QD_LOG_INFO, "Version: %s", QPID_DISPATCH_VERSION);
```

I am able to get to it, with

```
% strings core.20200730-1203 | grep -A3 -B3 "Version: "
Activating management agent on $_management_internal
router
Router Engine Instantiated: id=router-default-0 instance=1596103149 max_routers=128
Version: 1.13.0-SNAPSHOT
Router started in Interior mode, area=0 id=router-default-0
Container Name: router-default-0
Milan
```

but this is probably just an accident, a log line which was still present in the memory at the moment of crash.

What is a reliable way to encode and recover the version information?

Comment: I stand corrected. Core dumps don't include the program code of the executed binary.